# Source code of "Closure" class in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

`RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware of Laravel uses a class called Closure.

Code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Now, I need to find out the source code of that above mentioned Closure class. I'm passing hard times to understand how this `next()` method is functioning here.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a PHP class, that you often see used via anonymous functions: http://php.net/closure.

You'll usually see it used something like this: `someMethod(function ($foo) { return $foo->bar(); });`

Comment: @FatBoyXPC how " function ($foo) { return $foo->bar(); } " is directly following Closure class?

Comment: Just read the docs that I linked and these as well http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php.

Comment: @FatBoyXPC above mentioned two links really make sense to me. I've read those very carefully. After reading those links my realization is as such: An anonymous functions automatically a instance of Closure class. However, I don't know why people making down vote to this pin point specific question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you'll want to read up on [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware). They are basically a list/stack where you have various things happening before you get to the route handler (usually a controller). The `$next` parameter is a callback that calls the next middleware in the stack.

To figure out what `$next` is, you'll need to figure out the middleware that comes *after* `RedirectIfAuthenticated`. The easiest way to tell that is to `php artisan route:list` and look at all the middleware for that route, then look at `$middlewarePriority`. If the middlewares are not found in the priority variable, then middleware if first in first out, in that if you specify multiple middlewares for a route, the first one defined happens first.

If you only have a single middleware on the route then you are getting to the route, unless you're using other things such as [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation).